# How to set javascript variable as php variable and store it in database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<form action="" method="post" name="theform">
  <table width="693" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td width="683" id="mymessage" contenteditable="true" name="mymessage">Write message here...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
document.getElementById("mymessage").addEventListener("click", removePlace);    
function removePlace()
{
    document.getElementById("mymessage").innerHTML="";
}
</script>
<div id="google_translate_element"><span class="notranslate">Select language to translate your text above:</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() 
{
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,fr,it,ja,ko,ms,ru,ta,th,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<input type="hidden" id='hiddenInput' name='hiddenInput'>
  <span class="notranslate"><input type="submit" id="btnSend" name="btnSend" value="Send"></span>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("btnSend").onclick = function() { 
var tmsg = document.getElementById("mymessage").text;
var msg = document.getElementById("mymessage").innerHTML;
var tmsg = msg;
var newmsg = tmsg.replace(/<font>/g, "");
var newmsg1 = newmsg.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg2 = newmsg1.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg3 = newmsg2.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg4 = newmsg3.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg5 = newmsg4.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg6 = newmsg5.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg7 = newmsg6.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg8 = newmsg7.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg9 = newmsg8.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg10 = newmsg9.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg11 = newmsg10.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg12 = newmsg11.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg13 = newmsg12.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg14 = newmsg13.replace("</font>", "");
var newmsg15 = newmsg14.replace("</font>", "");
};
</script>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mytranslateim";
$password = "qwerty";
$dbname = "test";
$dbconnectivity = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (isset($_POST['btnSend']))
{
    $getmsg = newmsg15;
    if($getmsg == "")
    {
        echo "nothing";
    }
    else
    {
    echo $getmsg;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testing(testmsg) VALUES ('$getmsg')";//if i translated a text, for example i translate the word "test" in chinese, it will echo in chinese but will not save in database as chinese 
    $insertit = mysqli_query($dbconnectivity, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

How can i store a javascript variable as a php variable and store it in the database? For example, i want to set javascript var newmsg15 as php variable $getmsg. After that i want to store it in the database. How can i do so? Please help me thanks.

Comment: Ajax is the only way to pass javascript variable to PHP

Comment: @AkhilVL, I strongly disagree with you...

Comment: he already have form in code, why does he need any ajax?

Comment: You can use a HTML form and use input hidden to pass some variables. Ajax is not the only way.

Comment: Cool! I mean $phpval = jsval is not possible

Comment: how can i do it then? please let me know.

Comment: @Ivan check my answer and try

Answer (score 0):

> How can i store a javascript variable as a php variable

**Does it make any scene to you?**

You don't need to user javascript variables as a php but you need some data from client side in server side.

What you can do in your case is collect all data you want from script in array or json and pass it to server by submitting form.

Before submitting you form you need to execute this 
Code:

```
   for(i=0; i< yourArray.lengt;i++){
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT"); // Create a <input> node
    input.name="data[]";
    input.value=yourArray[i];                              
    document.getElementById("yourform").appendChild(input); 
    }
```

And this will give you array of your data in server side.

Hope this will help you.